# Setting binary path in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-14

I am trying to import data for a table from a csv file. Whenever I click on "Import.." after right clicking on the table, I get the following error message:
" Please configure the PostgreSQL Binary Path in the Preferences dialog "

As mentioned in the answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/149879/239955) , when I open preferences, I see multiple line items. None of these are for PostgreSQL 14.

[image: Preferences>Paths>Binary Paths]

The other solutions do not work either. [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/291536/239955) and [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/295557/239955)

Comment: Please disclose the version of pgAdmin and Postgres in use.

Comment: pgAdmin version 5.7,
PostgreSQL 14,
Windows 10

Comment: I see the same problem. pgAdmin releases new versions every 4 weeks. Postgres 14 was released just a week ago. I'd expect the next version of pgAdmin4 tomorrow, 2021-10-07, with a fix for this. If not, report a bug.

Comment: Thank you! I will do that